# XML Schema: Validate distinct pair of elements

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I try to produce the XML Schema in order to validate an xml file that should not allow a couple of same elements to appear more than once.

Under  there should be several  elements. Under every , there must be a pair of parts, and this combination should be unique.

XSD 1.1 and XPath 2.0 are used, and I've tried several solutions, such as count() eq count(distinct()), count() eq 1, every & preceding-siblings.

An attempt is this:

```
<xs:assert test="count( box/part[1]/@label/text() || box/part[2]/@label/text() ) 
                 eq count( distinct-values( box/part[1]/@label/text() ||
                                            box/part[2]/@label/text() ) )"/>
```

And another one is this:

```
<xs:assert test="count(box) eq count(box[ not ( preceding-sibling::box/part[1]/[@label 
                                                =current()/part[1]/@label]  or
                                                preceding-sibling::box/part[2]/[@label 
                                                = current()/part[1]/@label] ) ])"/>
```

To be more specific, this should be valid:

```
<box_list>
    <box>
        <part label="aaa"/>
        <part label="bbb"/>
        <random_el id="8"/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <part label="ccc"/>
        <part label="iii"/>
        <random_el height="9"/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <part label="aaa"/>
        <part label="kkk"/>
        <random_el id="5"/>
    </box>
</box_list>
```

And the following must be invalid:

```
<box_list>
    <box>
        <part label="aaa"/>
        <part label="bbb"/>
        <random_el id="8"/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <part label="aaa"/>
        <part label="bbb"/>
        <random_el height="9"/>
    </box>
    <box>
        <part label="aaa"/>
        <part label="kkk"/>
        <random_el id="5"/>
    </box>
</box_list>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question whether it would be valid to have one box with parts (aaa, bbb) and another with parts (bbb, aaa).

Assuming this would be valid, then you could use `count(box) = count(distinct-values(box/concat(part[1]/@label, part[2]/@label))`

Note that `@label/text()` selects nothing. Attribute nodes do not have children.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael! Unfortunately, (aaa,bbb) and (bbb,aaa) in the same xml is not valid. Is there any other approach in order to validate it?

Comment: With only two parts, you could use `distinct-values((part[1]/@label||part[2]/@label, part[2]/@label||part[1]/@label))`. Doing arbitrary permutations on a larger set is tricky; with XPath 3.1 you can use fn:sort() to normalize the order.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Kay for your immediate response! Eventually I solved it as I posted before.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xs:assert test="2*count(box) eq ( count( distinct-values((box/concat(part[1]/@label, part[2]/@label),
                                                           box/concat(part[2]/@label, part[1]/@label))) ) + 
                                   count( box[part[1]/@label eq part[2]/@label] ) )"/>
```